# Best approach to define a constant (used in a constant expression) in the class?

Tags: c++, constants

I am trying to define a constant BUFFER_LENGTH for my class for a given usecase.

```
//1. Using preprocessor declaration
//#define BUFFER_LENGTH  12

//2.Global constant
//const int BUFFER_LENGTH  = 12;
class MyRequest
{
public:
    //3. Define an in-class constant
    //static const int BUFFER_LENGTH = 12;

    //4. Declare an enum constant
    enum 
    {
        BUFFER_LENGTH = 12
    };

    MyRequest()
    {
        strcpy(mBuffer, "TestString");
        printf("Buffer: %s, BUFFER_LENGTH = %d",mBuffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
    }
private:
    char mBuffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
};
```

I just listed down the different ways in which constant can be defined for the class.

```
1. Using Preprocessor constant
2. Using Global constant
3. Using in-class constant
4. using an enum.
```

Out of these, which is the best approach to define the constants for the given use case? I prefer to use the enum constant over others approaches.
Is there any other better approach which I have missed out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

An enumerate type is not meant to define a numeric constant, though it's (ab)used for that a lot in template-metaprogramming.

If the constant's meaning is entangled with the class, I would define it in there.  Then you're still having two choices:

```
 class WithConst {
 public:

     // 1. as a const static member variable
     static const int sc_nNumber = 100; // I can initialize here for
                                        // integral-types only

     // 2. as a static member function - possibly inlined.
     static int sf_nNumber() { return 100; }
 };
```

The plus-side of the second choice is that you don't need to alter any client code later when you want to e.g. read the constant out of the registry, or a config file.

Comment: The second example is not a "constant integral expression" under the current rules of the standard and so cannot be used for example as an array index.

Comment: You'll have to wait a bit before static constexpr int sf_nNumber() { return 100; } is a valid const expression.

Comment: @Josh: indeed!  C++0x defines the 'constexpr' keyword to annotate this.  (somehow it rang a bell)

Answer (score 9):

It is always better for maintenance purposes to restrict the scope of any name (be it function, variable or constant) as much as possible.  So I would suggest either

```
static const int BUFFER_LENGTH = 12;
```

or

```
enum { BUFFER_LENGTH = 12 };
```

*inside* the class definition.

There isn't much benefit to the former, except that you can explicitly control the type.  `enum` causes C++ to choose an unspecified integral "underlying type" for you -- it could be as small as `char` if your enum contains only small values, though empirically, most compilers by default will use an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The static const member variable is the best - it's concise, solves the problem completely and guarantees that no conflicts will occur with other similar classes (that is quite possible with preprocessor definition or global constant). I suggest that you declare it in CamelCase rather that in all capitals with undescores so that it doesn't look as something special but as a normal class member which it really is.

Answer (score 2):

I read in "Thinking in C++" that the "enum-hack" was used in the past, because some compilers didn't support "static const" class members :
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_c++/Chapter08_023.html

So if you are using an antique compiler, or want to support them use the enum-hack. (I have no idea HOW old they must be to not support static const)

Comment: I have VC 6 compiler. I *doesnot* support static const class memebers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if they are completely interchangeable in this specific case. Since you are basing the size of an array member on the constant, I believe that it has to be an enumerated value. I don't have the time to look it up in the Standard, but I would be surprised if you can use an `int` member as an array size even if it is `static const` since the actual value might not be visible in the header.

```
// === in myclass.h
class MyClass {
public:
    static const int MY_SIZE;
private:
    int ary[MY_SIZE];
};

// === in myclass.cpp
/*static*/ const int MyClass::MY_SIZE = 10;

// === in otherclass.cpp
void OtherClass::operation(MyClass& obj) {
    std::cout << "Sizeof(MyClass) = " << sizeof(obj) << std::endl;
}
```

I don't think that the compiler can compile `otherclass.cpp` without having already compiled `myclass.cpp`.

In most other cases, I would say *Go with the class static constant* option since it will participate a little more intelligently in type deduction and such. I only use enumerated integer constants when I really need to or when they are truly enumerated constants (of course).

#### Edit

I just took a look at the Standard whilst I was munching away on lunch (Thanks for the nudge David)

> An *integer constant-expression* can involve only literals (2.13), enumerators,
>   `const` variables or static data members of integral or enumeration types initialized
>   with constant expressions (8.5), non-type template parameters of integral or
>   enumeration types, and `sizeof` expressions.

It looks like the constant and enum will both work provided that you provide the constant initializer in the declaration (or is that definition?).

Comment: In standard C++, a const int is a compile-time constant, and may be used as such.  You have to initialize on declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Using const int can be less efficient than using enum, below is a program that demonstrates this. Compiled with Metrowerks CodeWarrior 8.x for Windows, it shows that an object of a class that defines a constant as const int takes 4 bytes of memory more than a similar class that defines this constant as enum:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class foo {
    enum { MY_CONST = 1 };
    int x;
    public:
    foo();
};
class bar {
    const int MY_CONST;
    int x;
    public:
    bar();
};

int main() {
    printf( "%u %u\n", sizeof( foo), sizeof( bar));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It produces: "4 8"

Constructors were added to prevent aggressive optimization by the compiler. Because the program does not create objects of these types, constructors don't have to be actually defined in a separate compilation module. The same is true for the const int

Answer (score 0):

In reading previous posts i noticed that no one mentioned an "enum in a namespace" trick.  If you like enums because you are working on an older compiler (I've had such experience on VxWorks/Tornado embedded programming platform), then listen up: you can avoid naming collisions by placing enum inside a namespace or (if namespaces aren't supported either) inside a class.